# Two instances of one directive are using same instance of template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is an interesting problem.

I'm trying to create directive, which suppresses original `ng-click` action, shows modal box with question and executes original action after confirmation, something like question dialog box.

The problem is I want to use only one modal template for all directive instances on the page (I don't want to trash DOM with exactly same element) and I want to place it only once in the document body. With that solution I kind of have two scopes attached to one element in DOM. Almost everything works, it shows proper question on the box, but it triggers action after confirmation on every directive instance.

Below is fragment of code which suppress original click, instead invokes internal `clickHandler` which shows modal box. It also shows how modal element is append to document body and compiled.

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    element
      .off("click")
      .bind("click", function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.resetValues();
        });
        scope.populateValues();
        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (scope.clickHandler) scope.clickHandler();
        });
      });

    var modal = $("#myModal");
    if (!modal.length) {
      var templ = $templateCache.get("confirmationModalTemplate.html");
      modal = $(templ);
      $("body").after(modal);
    }
    scope.modal = $compile(modal)(scope);
```

[Here is an example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sboTot?p=preview)
.

You can see how confirmation of any action triggers both first and second.

Trick with double $apply ensure, that proper values of box title and content are shown.

How to fix it, so action will only be triggered once? I was thinking of switching scope of element, but couldn't find such an option.

Comment: Get rid of using bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap. Their modal service will manage templates for you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line `$("body").after(modal);`
You don't need to append the modal yourself.

`scope.modal.modal("show");` will do this for you. It's part of of the bootstrap library.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precisely what I need after all. It creates element and adds it twice (or more) to the DOM treee. I wanted to avoid that and just reuse same element.